# Python IDLE no longer opens after clicking on its icon

Tags: python, windows-10, python-idle

I was able to use python IDLE earlier. But when I tried to open now, I was unable to open Python 3.7 IDLE. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python(different versions) and deleting the .idlerc folder. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

**If you still have your python installer in your Downloads folder, you can repair your version of python, by:**

1. Double-Click on the python installer. If your version of python and the installer's version are same their should be an option to repair click on it, Wait...
2. After it's finished, Reboot/Restart your PC/Laptop
3. Try running IDLE again.

If this doesn't solves your question, or have any queries and doubts about it feel free to ask about it to me!
Happy Coding!

Comment: tried but still Python idle doesn't open.

Comment: @AvinashGaur In this case there are two options, permanently delete whole python installation from windows 10 Settings or for windows 7 control panel and if there is still there is a python folder in the installation directory just ```SHIFT+DEL``` it, and then reinstall python again, the second option is to download a new text editor or IDE, here are some recommended ones- IDEs: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/, https://code.visualstudio.com/. TEXT EDITOR: https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Comment: I have already tried the first part of you suggestion by installing different versions. But still the problem remains. As for the second part, I need Idle to compile my code. I already have sublime text but as far as I know it is not a great choice for compiling code

Comment: You can use also use CMD to compile your code, just navigate to your working directory and then run ```python filename.py``` to compile your code, directly, if you still want to use IDLE there's not much that I can help you with now on :-(

Comment: Thanks Aryan for your time. But, I need python for Computer vision for which I will need Idle.

Comment: After deleting the Environment Variables with Python references, it started working:). Don't know how it solved the problem but I am happy that it is resolved.